# How to set all values of a field as body classes

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

I want users to easily modify the layout of a node by selecting options in a 'Layout' field that the node contains. The field is a entityreference field referencing taxonomy terms. 
(For example, the user can select term 'hide-images' and the body class 'hide-images' will be used in the css to hide images.)

I have found this code that sets the first value of a field as body class. 
But how can I add all field values (taxonomy terms) as body classes?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html
 */
function THEME_preprocess_html(&$vars){
  // Check if on an article node page
  if($node = menu_get_object('node') && $node->type == 'article'){
    // Get field values
    if($term = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_layout')){
      // Add first term value to body class
      $vars['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class(reset($term));
     }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you could take a look at [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds).  DS has this functionality built in.

DS comes with a sub-module (DS extras) that has a feature that allows users to select a style right from the node edit page.

After enabling ds, ds_ui, ds_extras you can enable `/admin/structure/ds/list/extras` -> Other Tab -> View mode per node to use the feature.

Description of the feature:

> Change view modes for individual nodes. A new tab 'Display settings'
>   will appear on the content create form. You can also pass the name of
>   a view mode through the URL, eg node/x?v=full. If you install the Page
>   manager module and override the node view, Page manager will win.

Update: If you still want to do it the way you started, you can just change this bit to use a foreach:

Change:

```
if($term = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_layout')){
  $vars['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class(reset($term));
}
```

To:

```
if ($term = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_layout')) {
  foreach ($term as $item) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class($item['taxonomy_term']->name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I want to keep the solution light-weight and installing Display Suite would be an overkill in my case.

Comment: @Yuri - updated to use your existing code

Comment: Is there an Drupal 8 version of this answer?

Answer (score 1):

For D8:

Using `template_preprocess_html()`

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 */
function themename_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // CSS Class on the basis of Color Selection.
  $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
  if ($node->getType() == 'article') {
    $node_array = $node->toArray();
    $field_color = reset($node_array['field_color']);
    $color_class = 'color-' . $field_color['color'];
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = $color_class;
  }
}
```

Using `template_preprocess_page()`

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_page().
 */
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // CSS Class on the basis of Color Selection.
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ($node->getType() == 'article') {
    $node_array = $variables['node']->toArray();
    $field_color = reset($node_array['field_color']);
    $color_class = 'color-' . $field_color['color'];
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = $color_class;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! Do you have any idea how this code would be when using  the Group module, using terms of a Group entity? for D8. I'm actually using the groups in Open Social.